# Modifying the SQL Eloquent uses per connection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using the latest version of Laravel to connect to multiple data sources. One of those sources is an old Oracle database that contains a lot of white space thanks to some ancient software requiring string length. Despite this constraint, the fields have since been edited by new software with different requirements, and the columns are all varying length (and thus unknown).

On account of this, I need to edit the SQL that accesses it in order to wrap some pieces of the queries in trim()s. For instance,

`$customer = Customer::whereRaw("RTRIM(\"ID\") = TO_CHAR($id)")->get();`

I'd like to be able to merely call the find method:

`$customer = Customer::find($id)`

This is just one example. Pretty much all of the default functions are broken because the queries need some kind of trim prepended to them. I understand how I can affect the dynamic portion of the query, but I need to edit the column ahead of that. Sorry if this is a dumb question and I've just missed something in the documentation.

Comment: To clarify, I'd like to be able to edit, for example, the find() function for an entire DB::connection(). If there's a better method, I'm all ears.

Comment: The best way would probably create a function inside of the model to create the query. If you don't want to add the function to all of the models, then create a new class to extend Eloquent, add the function there, then have the models extend the new class.

Comment: I'm open to editing the query in the model, however this is going to be a large project pulling in something like 30 apps this business is using, and there will inevitably be many many models. There is a two year plan to update the software that is using the Oracle database, and at that time we can update Oracle, and then modify the fields with some kind of batch query. So while I can edit all the models at that time, it would be easier for future me if I only had to edit the one base class. I may do your second option. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Actually, I think I will go that route. If you want to submit the parent::parent extension as an answer I'll accept that.

Comment: You could probably extend the base Eloquent/Model class and make that load in as the default Model class via the app.php, if you then extend Eloquent that has been lazy loaded you can basicly swap out between the custom Eloquent extension and the default one. Seems easier than editing all the models if you ever needed to switch again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a class that extends Eloquent, with the function for the query. Then modify all of your models to extend the new class instead of Eloquent. This way the models will have all the functionality of Eloquent as well as the functions you create.

Comment: Thank you for setting me straight, friend.